# Null POST with data passed via AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a Bootstrap table which is being filled with data retrieved from a database. Each row of the table represents one record from the database, and has a button next to it to perform another function (not yet implemented). I've tried to set this up so that when the user clicks the button, the row id is set via AJAX to another PHP file to process it. However, I can't get this to work.

Using Firebug I can see that the POST request is being sent, and contains the data as I would expect (as you can see below).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/60B7i.png

However, in the approve.php file I've got the following code:

```
<?php
    $request = $_GET['request_id'];

    var_dump($_GET['request_id']);
?>
```

Firebug shows this response as being "NULL", and I'm at a loss to why. So far as I can see, the number one should be grabbed and then displayed back to me. This is the code for the button:

```
<td id="approve"><button class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-xs approveButton" data-id="<?php echo $row['request_id']; ?>">Approve</button></td>
```

and here is the AJAX/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".approveButton").click( function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "core/actions/approve.php",
                        data: {request_id: $(this).attr('data-id')}
                    });
                    $(this).parent().parent("tr:first").remove()
                });
});
```

If anyone has any ideas as to why this is happening I'd appreciate it very much. Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you looking at `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a POST request and looking in `$_GET`. Use `$_POST`.

Comment: Dear lord.. I'm such an idiot. Thanks so much - I've been working on this project for the last 3 hours and my mind is fried.

Answer (score 0):

To get `POST` request data you need to use `$request = $_POST['request_id'];` instead of `$_GET`